# How to rename video file in android

Tags: android, file, video, android-videoview, android-file

I try to rename video file with this code:

```
File from = new File(outputFileName);
            File to = new File(mediaStorageDir,mediaFile);
            from.renameTo(to);
```

when

`outputFileName = //mnt/sdcard/Movies/Your_voice/Your_voice.mp4`

and

```
mediaFile = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "Your_voice" +
                    timeStamp +
                    ".mp4";
```

and

```
mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
                "Your_voice");
```

no error in locat .... but not execute rename.

I thought this problem cause because this file play in videoview so before the code I add `videoView.setVideoPath("");` but it dont help, what I need to do ???

thanks ahead...

Comment: what's the value of mediaStorageDir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already specify the `mediaStorageDir` when constructing the File object:

```
File to = new File(mediaStorageDir,mediaFile);
```

so you should remove the `mediaStorageDir.getPath()` from `mediaFile`, as follows:

```
mediaFile = "Your_voice" + timeStamp + ".mp4";
```

You should probably also remove the `Your_voice` part from the mediaStorageDir, just use:

```
mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
```